# Cassandra read_request_timeout_in_ms set up for external(Client) request

Tags: java, cassandra, nosql, cassandra-3.0, cqlsh

As per Documentation and given knowledge on the internet. It seems that the below-given properties

```
- request_timeout_in_ms

- write_request_timeout_in_ms

- read_request_timeout_in_ms
```

Works only for internal(server side) Cassandra requests. I was even convinced to this fact when I set these parameters in `cassandra.yaml` file to `80000` but still got the Timeout error against my Select query to a bit bigger record by following two ways:

 **1)** when I tried to connect to Cassandra via cqlsh without additional parameter `--request-timeout=80000`. by adding this parameter, I was able to run select statment successfully which was being failed last time.

**2)** When I tried to update the same record via java client using Cassandra driver without setting up `new SocketOptions().setReadTimeoutMillis(80000)` in `Cluster.Builder` creation.
**Question:** 
Is there are way to set these request_timeout parameters to Cassandra  for external(client side) requests as well (So I don't have to mention these values while connecting via Cqlsh or javaclient or DevCenter by DataStax)?

Comment: The reason it is available at the client level is to provide flexibility and specifically not controlled by the server settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server cant really enforce a client side timeout as well, as there are delays that occur outside the server. An example is a delay introduced by the linux kernel in sending the request, then a 300ms latency spike cross DC, your client is getting the request 500ms after the app sent it.

Worse comes in play with GCs, ie C* sends the response, but then has a 2 second STW gc pause. The request has been "completed" from server perspective but the client will have an additional 2 second delay. If your server is poorly configured you can easily see a 8 second GC periodically. The timeout on the server side is as best as it can handle given unknowable (or prohibitively unknowable at least) factors outside its control. If you have a strict timeout its best to handle it on the client side. I would recommend doing it in your request handler.

```
ListenableFuture result = Futures.withTimeout(session.executeAsync(/*statement*/),
                                              8, TimeUnit.SECONDS, executor)
```

`setReadTimeoutMillis` is a little nuanced, its per request but a `execute/executeAsync` can end up being multiple requests, as it will try multiple hosts potentially as part of query plan (retry/speculative retry). So for example a RF=3 request on LOCAL_ONE with `setReadTimeoutMillis` of 2 could actually take 6 seconds to timeout depending on retry policy.

Comment: Well Explained @Chris. You mentioned to use ListenableFuture. Is there any difference using new SocketOptions().setReadTimeoutMillis(95000); rather then ListenableFuture?

Comment: In the setReadTimeoutMillis, you will use the same timeout for all the queries in the code. But, the listenablefuture is limited to particular query, as all the queries do not require the same large timeout.

Comment: I updated with a note about setReadTimeoutMillis, it wont necessarily cap your request at that time

Comment: @ChakriStark is there any overhead of adding setReadTimeoutMillis for overall queries? if no, why would I do extra work to set them separate ?

Comment: @Freak there is no overhead at all.. I am just explaining the basic difference for your question in the previous comment

Comment: @ChakriStark appreciated !!